# Как сделать портабельным файл базы данных формата mdf

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Есть простой код вывода содержимого строк из базы. Имя бд, созданной в sql server'e "infodb", имя таблицы "infoTable". Код рабочий.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=infodb;Integrated Security=True";

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {                    
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlex = "select * from infoTable";
            var cmnd = new SqlCommand(sqlex, connection);            
            var reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    textBox1.Text += reader.GetValue(i) + "\t";
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Но когда указываешь Initial Catalog какой либо другой,даже тот же самый (но прописанный руками!) C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA, то ошибка. AttachDBFilename ситуацию не изменил. С ним все получается, когда создаешь базу в студии через Добавление нового компонента: "База данных, основанная на службах" - DataBase1.mdf. Эта штука работает, если на компе стоит sql server (т.к. имеется строка подключения). Вопрос, как не используя Access с его (mdb - базой) решить эту проблему: сделать так, чтобы я мог свое приложение развернуть на любом компе без sql server'a ?

Comment: На том компьютере, где будет использоваться ваша программа, обязательно должна быть установлена СУБД SqlServer (может быть бесплатная версия Express). Точка. Без СУБД работа невозможна.

Comment: Если не хотите зависеть от внешних СУБД, используйте встраиваемый движок. Например, sqlite.